# Navbar collapse is not working in Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On phone view The **Navbar** works just File in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) but it is not expanding in my site.
Here is the full page Code-

```
    <html lang="en"><head>
    <title>Your store</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="generator" content="nopCommerce">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


    <link href="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/bootstrap-3.2.0/CSS/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Content/jquery-ui-themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/public.common.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/public.ajaxcart.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>









<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:38451/favicon.ico">
    <!--Powered by nopCommerce - http://www.nopCommerce.com-->
    <!--Copyright (c) 2008-2013-->
<style type="text/css">.fb_hidden{position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}.fb_invisible{display:none}.fb_reset{background:none;border:0;border-spacing:0;color:#000;cursor:auto;direction:ltr;font-family:"lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:1;margin:0;overflow:visible;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;text-indent:0;text-shadow:none;text-transform:none;visibility:visible;white-space:normal;word-spacing:normal}.fb_reset>div{overflow:hidden}.fb_link img{border:none}
.fb_dialog{background:rgba(82, 82, 82, .7);position:absolute;top:-10000px;z-index:10001}.fb_reset .fb_dialog_legacy{overflow:visible}.fb_dialog_advanced{padding:10px;-moz-border-radius:8px;-webkit-border-radius:8px;border-radius:8px}.fb_dialog_content{background:#fff;color:#333}.fb_dialog_close_icon{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;_background-image:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/s816eWC-2sl.gif);cursor:pointer;display:block;height:15px;position:absolute;right:18px;top:17px;width:15px}.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{top:5px;left:5px;right:auto}.fb_dialog_padding{background-color:transparent;position:absolute;width:1px;z-index:-1}.fb_dialog_close_icon:hover{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -15px transparent;_background-image:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/s816eWC-2sl.gif)}.fb_dialog_close_icon:active{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yq/r/IE9JII6Z1Ys.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -30px transparent;_background-image:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yL/r/s816eWC-2sl.gif)}.fb_dialog_loader{background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #606060;font-size:24px;padding:20px}.fb_dialog_top_left,.fb_dialog_top_right,.fb_dialog_bottom_left,.fb_dialog_bottom_right{height:10px;width:10px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute}.fb_dialog_top_left{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 0;left:-10px;top:-10px}.fb_dialog_top_right{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -10px;right:-10px;top:-10px}.fb_dialog_bottom_left{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -20px;bottom:-10px;left:-10px}.fb_dialog_bottom_right{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/8YeTNIlTZjm.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;right:-10px;bottom:-10px}.fb_dialog_vert_left,.fb_dialog_vert_right,.fb_dialog_horiz_top,.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{position:absolute;background:#525252;filter:alpha(opacity=70);opacity:.7}.fb_dialog_vert_left,.fb_dialog_vert_right{width:10px;height:100%}.fb_dialog_vert_left{margin-left:-10px}.fb_dialog_vert_right{right:0;margin-right:-10px}.fb_dialog_horiz_top,.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{width:100%;height:10px}.fb_dialog_horiz_top{margin-top:-10px}.fb_dialog_horiz_bottom{bottom:0;margin-bottom:-10px}.fb_dialog_iframe{line-height:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title{background:#6d84b4;border:1px solid #3b5998;color:#fff;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin:0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_title>span{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/Cou7n-nqK52.gif) no-repeat 5px 50%;float:left;padding:5px 0 7px 26px}body.fb_hidden{-webkit-transform:none;height:100%;margin:0;overflow:visible;position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:0;width:100%}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ya/r/3rhSv5V8j3o.gif) white no-repeat 50% 50%;min-height:100%;min-width:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;z-index:10001}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading.centered{max-height:590px;min-height:590px;max-width:500px;min-width:500px}#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay{background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;z-index:10000}#fb-root #fb_dialog_ipad_overlay.hidden{display:none}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile.loading iframe{visibility:hidden}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header{-webkit-box-shadow:white 0 1px 1px -1px inset;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#738ABA), to(#2C4987));border-bottom:1px solid;border-color:#1d4088;color:#fff;font:14px Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;text-overflow:ellipsis;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0;vertical-align:middle;white-space:nowrap}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header table{-webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;height:43px;width:100%}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_left{font-size:12px;padding-left:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header td.header_right{font-size:12px;padding-right:5px;vertical-align:middle;width:60px}.fb_dialog_content .touchable_button{background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#4966A6), color-stop(.5, #355492), to(#2A4887));border:1px solid #29447e;-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, .117188) 0 1px 1px inset, rgba(255, 255, 255, .167969) 0 1px 0;display:inline-block;margin-top:3px;max-width:85px;line-height:18px;padding:4px 12px;position:relative}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .touchable_button input{border:none;background:none;color:#fff;font:12px Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;margin:2px -12px;padding:2px 6px 3px 6px;text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_header .header_center{color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;line-height:18px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_content{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;border:1px solid #555;border-bottom:0;border-top:0;height:150px}.fb_dialog_content .dialog_footer{background:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #555;border-top-color:#ccc;height:40px}#fb_dialog_loader_close{float:left}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_button{text-shadow:rgba(0, 30, 84, .296875) 0 -1px 0}.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_mobile .fb_dialog_close_icon{visibility:hidden}
.fb_iframe_widget{display:inline-block;position:relative}.fb_iframe_widget span{display:inline-block;position:relative;text-align:justify}.fb_iframe_widget iframe{position:absolute}.fb_iframe_widget_lift{z-index:1}.fb_hide_iframes iframe{position:relative;left:-10000px}.fb_iframe_widget_loader{position:relative;display:inline-block}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid{display:inline}.fb_iframe_widget_fluid span{width:100%}.fb_iframe_widget_loader iframe{min-height:32px;z-index:2;zoom:1}.fb_iframe_widget_loader .FB_Loader{background:url(http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y9/r/jKEcVPZFk-2.gif) no-repeat;height:32px;width:32px;margin-left:-16px;position:absolute;left:50%;z-index:4}
.fbpluginrecommendationsbarleft,.fbpluginrecommendationsbarright{position:fixed !important;bottom:0;z-index:999}.fbpluginrecommendationsbarleft{left:10px}.fbpluginrecommendationsbarright{right:10px}</style></head>
<body>




<div id="dialog-notifications-success" title="Notification" style="display:none; width:600px;">
</div>
<div id="dialog-notifications-error" title="Error" style="display:none;">
</div>
<div id="bar-notification" class="bar-notification">
    <img src="/Content/Images/ico-close-notification-bar.png" class="close" alt="Close" title="Close">
</div>


<div class="headerwrapper">
    <div class="header ">
<div class="container top-header-container shadowwrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a href="/" class="logo img-responsive">&nbsp; </a>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <link href="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/flyout/flyout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/flyout/flyout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div class="social_container_login">
        <div class="social_container">
        <div><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Brookhaven-Marketplace/33148540039"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/social/big_facebook_icon.png" alt="Facebook"></a></div>
        <div><a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/#!/brookhavenmkt"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/social/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></div>
        <div><a target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/brookhavenmkrt/"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/social/icon_pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest"></a></div>
    </div>


    <div class="login"> 
        <a href="#login-box" class="login-window">My Account</a>
    </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a class="see-u-picks" href="../../../specialcouponoffer"><img class="img-responsive" src="/content/images/uploaded/See-current-upick-offer-btn.png"></a>   
</div>



<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <a href="#" class="close"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close"></a>

    <div class="header-links">
        <h1>My Account</h1>
        <ul>


                <li><a href="/ShoppingList">Shopping List</a></li>
                <li><a href="/customer/info" class="account">Preferences</a></li>
                <li><a href="/logout" class="ico-logout">Log out</a></li>
                            <li id="topcartlink"><a href="/cart" class="ico-cart">Shopping cart</a>
                    <a href="/cart" class="cart-qty">(16)</a>
                </li>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('#topcartlink').live('mouseenter', function () {
                        $('#flyout-cart').addClass('active');
                    });
                    $('#topcartlink').live('mouseleave', function () {
                        $('#flyout-cart').removeClass('active');
                    });
                    $('#flyout-cart').live('mouseenter', function () {
                        $('#flyout-cart').addClass('active');
                    });
                    $('#flyout-cart').live('mouseleave', function () {
                        $('#flyout-cart').removeClass('active');
                    });
                </script>
                            <li><a href="/wishlist" class="ico-wishlist">Wishlist</a> <a href="/wishlist" class="wishlist-qty">
                                                                                                    (1)</a> </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="topdownclickme">
        <div class="ico-myaccount">My Account</div></div>
    <script>$('.topdownclickme').click(function() {
                    $('.header-links').slideToggle('slow', function() {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                });
    </script>

</div>

    </div>

</div>









    <div class="header-selectors-wrapper">
        <div class="header-taxdisplaytypeselector">

        </div>
        <div class="header-currencyselector">



        </div>
        <div class="header-languageselector">



        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <div class="top-header-menu">


<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/print.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/nav/superfish.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        // initialise plugins
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish();
        });

        </script>






<div class="container shadowwrapper ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  ">

            <div class="headermenu">

                <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button data-target="#top-header-menu-proco" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div id="top-header-menu-proco" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                            <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/books">Books


                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Computers
                                    &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>





                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/desktops">Desktops


                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/notebooks">Notebooks


                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/accessories">Accessories


                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/software-games">Software &amp; Games


                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Electronics
                                    &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>





                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/camera-photo">Camera, photo


                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="/cell-phones">Cell phones


                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/apparel-shoes">Apparel &amp; Shoes


                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/digital-downloads">Digital downloads


                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/jewelry">Jewelry


                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/gift-cards">Gift Cards


                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>

</div>
<div class="background-wrapper">
    <div class="@*master-wrapper-page*@">

        <div class="@*master-wrapper-content*@">
            <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            //replace the first parameter with "true" to use popup notifications
                AjaxCart.init(true, '.header-links .cart-qty', '.header-links .wishlist-qty', '#flyout-cart');
            //]]>
        </script>



            <div class="ajax-loading-block-window" style="display: none">
                <div class="loading-image">
                </div>
            </div>


<div class="white-background container shadowwrapper">

    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 ">
    <div class="htmlcontent">
        <div class="htmlcontent-body">
            <div class="left-nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/t/Gluten-Free"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/HomePageLeft/glutenfree_promo.png" alt="" width="280" height="184"></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/t/Wine-Geek-Archives"><img src="http://brookhavenmarket.com/Content/Images/uploaded/HomePageLeft/winegeek.jpg" alt="" width="265" height="185"></a></li>
<!-- <li><a href="/t/Gluten-Free"><img width="280" height="184" src="/Content/Images/uploaded/HomePageLeft/glutenfree_promo.png" /></a></li> -->
<li><a href="/t/Are-you-an-active-member"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/HomePageLeft/lifetime_fitness_button.jpg" alt="" width="232" height="185"></a></li>
<!--<li><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/HomePageLeft/catering_promo.jpg" height="184" width="338" /></li>--></ul>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    <div class="clear">test
                    </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 ">
                <div class="">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/ProcoDefault/Content/flexslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          slideshowSpeed: 5000 
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="homepage_container">


    <div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset"><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div><iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_http" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" id="fb_xdm_frame_http" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tabindex="-1" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/KFZn1BJ0LYk.js?version=41#channel=f2cbd788b4&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A38451" style="border: none;"></iframe><iframe name="fb_xdm_frame_https" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" id="fb_xdm_frame_https" aria-hidden="true" title="Facebook Cross Domain Communication Frame" tabindex="-1" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/KFZn1BJ0LYk.js?version=41#channel=f2cbd788b4&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A38451" style="border: none;"></iframe></div></div><div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;"><div></div></div></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


    <div class="homepagebanners">    <div class="htmlcontent">
        <div class="htmlcontent-body">
            <div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: list-item; opacity: 0.347983469537255;"><a href="http://brookhavenmarket.com/Themes/Brookhaven/Content/email/special-eblast/Easter-2014/easter-menu-2014.pdf"><img src="http://brookhavenmarket.com/Content/Images/uploaded/HomeBanners/Easter-Menu-banner.jpg" alt="" width="634" height="216"></a></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;" class=""><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/recipes/3028"><img src="../../../Content/Images/uploaded/HomeBanners/4-16-2014-1.jpg" alt="" width="634" height="216"></a></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;" class=""><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/recipes/5126"><img src="../../../Content/Images/uploaded/HomeBanners/4-16-2014-2.jpg" alt="" width="634" height="216"></a></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;" class=""><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/content/images/uploaded/catering_menu/pdf/catering_menu.pdf"><img src="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/Content/Images/uploaded/HomeBanners/2013_catering_banner.jpg" alt="" width="634" height="216"></a></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: none;" class=""><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/t/Gluten-Free"><img src="http://brookhavenmarket.com/Content/Images/uploaded/HomeBanners/gluten-free-banner.jpg" alt="" width="634" height="216"></a></li>
<li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: list-item; opacity: 0.652016530462745;" class=""><a href="../../../t/Employment-Mission-Statement"><img src="../../../Content/Images/uploaded/HomeBanners/help_wanted.jpg" alt="" width="634" height="216"></a></li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a class="flex-active">1</a></li><li><a class="">2</a></li><li><a class="">3</a></li><li><a class="">4</a></li><li><a class="">5</a></li><li><a class="">6</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a></li></ul></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="homepagebottom">     <div class="htmlcontent">
        <div class="htmlcontent-body">
            <div class="homepageBlogContainer">
<p class="homepageBlogText"><a href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/blog"><span style="font-size: medium;"><strong><em>Easter Traditions with a Twist</em></strong></span></a></p>
<p>Easter is always a busy time at a food store ranking up there with the likes of Christmas and Thanksgiving as traditionally it’s a time when families gather together to share a meal. Not just any meal but what most would consider a feast. It’s a time when traditional foods that we have loved since childhood are planned, shopped for and prepared with great care and attention to detail. It’s a time when on most cases paper plates and plastic flatware are foregone in deference to Mom’s best china, crystal and silverware. Last week’s blog focused on our sweet tooth with suggested Easter Desserts. This week let’s concentrate on the main course....</p>
<p><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span lang="en-US">Okay, perhaps not. But we can still hope, can’t we?</span></span></span></p>
<p><span style="color: #800000;"><strong><span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: small;"><span lang="en-US">&nbsp;...</span></span></span><a style="font-size: small; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;" href="http://www.brookhavenmarket.com/blog"><span style="color: #800000;">read more</span></a></strong></span></p>
<div class="readmore"><a href="/blog" shape="rect"><img src="/Content/Images/uploaded/arrow.png" alt="" align="right"></a></div>
</div>
<div style="float: left;"><iframe style="width: 338px; height: 346px; overflow: hidden;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FBrookhaven-Marketplace%2F33148540039&amp;width=340&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=346" width="320" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="clear">
    </div>




    <div class="clear">
    </div>




</div>





                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>







        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer-wrapper">
<div class="container shadowwrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="footer ">
                    <div class="clear" style="height:1px"></div>

                    <a href="http://www.procomarketing.com"><img class="proco-logo" src="../themes/ProcoDefault/Content/images/proco_logo.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer-disclaimer">
    Copyright © 2014 Brookhaven Market. All rights reserved.
</div>

<div class="footer-storetheme">

</div>









</body></html>
```

I am using jquery-1.10.2.min.js. What could be the problem? There is showing no problem in console too. I already used navbar in many sites but never saw that kind of problem before. Please Help.

Comment: I don't see any actual code here, can you post your javascript?

Comment: That code is fine, there must be something else on your site that is interfering. Without seeing it, there's not a lot we can help with.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am using nopcommerce frontend codes, so it is quite impossible for me to show you all the files. I just pasted the index.html page. See if it hepls @DavidG

Comment: @Sujit You missed the `M` from `MVCE`!

Comment: I got two JS warnings 
`Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:56
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().` Does it cause this problem? @DavidG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap relies on jQuery but in your code you have presented the files for Bootstrap first. Change the order and it will work. Additionally you need to ensure your paths are correct as you seem to be missing the name of the theme.

As you mention in the comments, your code to include the scripts is:

```
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Themes/Content/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");
```

Simply change the order of the last 2 lines like this:

```
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");
Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Themes/ProcoDefault/Content/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js");
```

Comment: Here is the Razor Codes - `<br/>
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js");
    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Themes/Content/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js");

    Html.AppendScriptParts("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");<br/>`

But I don't see any script request for **bootstrap.min.js** .In Devtool Elements there is no script for bootstrap within head tag Why? It Compiles in descending order. Other Scripts are showing perfectly

Comment: For that Razor output is This-
`<br/>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script><br/>` in Head Tag. What should I do? Bootstrap.JS is missing and there is no error

Comment: In NopCommerce AppendScriptParts are build in Descending orders.I have that file in that folder.But the problem is, if file not found then it should show a 404 in console. But there is no errors.