# Bootstrap 3.2 Navbar not collapsing with jquery.min.map error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap for the first time and my navbar is not collapsing. So in response to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295394/navbar-collapse-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-3-2), I checked the order of `jquery` and `Bootstrap` js files and its OK.
When I checked the **Network** tab to check if all resources are loading correctly, I am getting `jquery.min.map` error that it can't be loaded.

Is my problem related due to this missing file and why Bootstrap is asking for this file?

Here is the image :
[image]
And when I further decrease the screen width, the links and search disappear and the expand button also does not appear.

Here is my code for `navbar` for the reference

```
<div class="container" id="main">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
            </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Founders <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Naveen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sumit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sanjeev</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Naveen</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navar-nav pull-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account</a> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: could you might add a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a [bootly](http://www.bootply.com/new) to show us the problem ?

Comment: @Dwza: Sorry but there is no Bootstrap in jsfiddle

Comment: Yes there is. Pick jQuery 2.1 and click bootstrap 3.2

Comment: Like Macsupport sayed, there is bootstrap :) And even if you don't have the right setup on jsfiddle you can use the second link (www.bootply.com) to use your jquery and bootstrap. Choose settings on the left top and simply select your jquery version. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out part of your nav html under navbar-header:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/hyn7p5ma/)